# Unable to use function imported from js file without extra <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, import

I'm trying to use a function that is defined in another js file.

The file structure is:

```
main.html
js/
  util.js
```

The following runs fine:

`main.html` is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"</script> 
    <script></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>

<script type="text/javascript">

const out = first([1, 2, 3, 4])
console.log(out)

</script>

</html>
```

`util.js` is:

```
alert("in util.js")

var first = function(arr) {
  return arr[0]
}
```

When I leave out line 4 (`<script></script>`) from `main.html`, I get the "in util.js" alert. However, the output of `first` is not logged.

I stumbled upon the solution of including the extra pair of script tags accidentally and it's unclear to me why it should be necessary. In addition, I haven't found any examples online that include this line.

Given this, I'm wondering (A) why `main.html` line 3 is insufficient on its own to source `first`, and (B) whether `main.html` line 4 is the preferred solution (again, I suspect it is not).

Any pointers appreciated!

Edit: Silly typo was the problem. Missing a ">"...

Comment: Look at the color coding in your above snippet..  It gives you a clue.   Your missing a `>` after your `"js/util.js"`  so ends up picking the closing tag from the line below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Keith in a comment.

The problem was a basic typo (missing ">"). Line 3 should read as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
```

Then, line 4 is not necessary.